# Vmware Workstation 12 Install Problem

Tags: 16.04, vmware, gcc

Having a tough time here. I have installed kernel 4.6 for my machine and using gcc 6.1.1 - so vmware workstation 12 installs fine but will not run. Does not find compatible gcc version 5.3.1

So wondering if anyone has a way to get this to work with gcc 6.1.1 or how to install 5.3.1 just for Vmware?

Thanks,

SJ

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue and found a solution. But I never consider about my gcc version. This solution works fine on kernel 4.6.x. Need to change some c codes.
Actually this solution for fedora but works well on Ubuntu 16.04 kernel 4.6.x.x.

1. find following archives on /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source

   - vmmon.tar
   - vmnet.tar

**Before make any changes backup original archives.**

2. untar vmmon.rar and find /vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c file and change "**get_user_pages**" to "**get_user_pages_remote**"
3. tar and replace original
4. untar vmnet.tar and find /vmnet-only/userif.c file and change "**get_user_pages**" to "**get_user_pages_remote**"
5. tar and replace original

then start vmware workstation.

source : https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1278896

Comment: Thanks I did try that but still not working. After that I run sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all. But I still get "failed to get gcc information"